Crystal Reports Summarize Detail by Conditional Groups
In Crystal Reports XI R2, I would like to split my details into two groups based on conditions. Currently the details show all parts and their names and costs in detail. I would like for products with a Product line of 0-99 to be summarized into a group labelled "Wood" and all parts with a product line 99-200 to be summarized into a line for "Metal." So essentially instead of 50+ part lines in the details section there would be 2 lines, Wood and Metal with the totals for the parts that fall into their criteria.
Tried creating a group with subgroup like group 1a and 1b but that did not work.

Just create a formula and add that as a group in Crystal.
Replace with correct field name and formatting.
IF ISNULL({PRODUCT.Product_line}) THEN 'Other'
Else
If {PRODUCT.Product_line} IN 0 to 99 then 'Wood'
Else
If {PRODUCT.Product_line} IN 100 to 200 then 'Metal'
Else
'Other'

